# same request, different response in nested describes suite

Tags: json, angularjs, jasmine

I'm newbie in AngularJS and testing with Jasmine. I have two describe with several httpBackend.whenPOST, but i dont know if its possible the next:

I want to include two nested describes, which the second uses all httpBackend.whenPost from the first one. But i want that one of these httpBackend.whenPost returns another Json having the same url. Is this possible?

```
describe('describe1', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
         $httpBackend.whenPOST(/backend\/economicresponsible\/get\/.*/).
           respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
           var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xmlhttp.open('POST', 'tests/json/economicData1.json', false);
           xmlhttp.send();
           return [200, JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response), {}];
        });
        .... more requests...
    });

    it('should be test', function(){
       get response economicData1.json
    });

    describe('describe2', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
         $httpBackend.whenPOST(/backend\/economicresponsible\/get\/.*/).
           respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
           var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xmlhttp.open('POST', 'tests/json/economicData2.json', false);
           xmlhttp.send();
           return [200, JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response), {}];
        });
       });

        it('should be test 2', function(){
           get response economicData2.json
        });
    });

});
```